# Why aren't the `vw`s and `vh`s scaling properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a frame. The `<div>` has a `width` of `90vw` and a `height` of `90vh`. Why isn't the `div` scaling properly when I resize the window?

Code:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
}

#frame {
  border-top: 8px solid orange;
  border-left: 16px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 8px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Why isn't the div scaling properly when I resize the window?" — It is scaling properly. Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `box-sizing: border-box;` for everything (`*`) to include the borders and the `padding` in the overall width and height, and use `margin: 0` instead of `padding: 0` for the `body` to reset the default margins.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  #frame {
    border-top: 8px solid orange;
    border-left: 16px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 8px solid orange;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
    padding: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="frame">
  <div id="content">

  </div>
</div>
```